# a slider Input in a react component does not slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

```
        <div className="bottom">
          <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" />
          <button className="button" onClick={submitHandler}>
            <span className="text">Add Want</span>
          </button>
        </div>
```

This is the most basic slider that I copied from a w3schools tutorial. Yet it doesn't slide. what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can use range slider.

```
export default function App() {
  const [rangeVal, setRangeVal] = useState(0);
  const submitHandler = () => {
    alert(rangeVal);
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setRangeVal(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="bottom">
        <input
          type="range"
          min="1"
          max="100"
          value={rangeVal}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button className="button" onClick={submitHandler}>
          <span className="text">Add Want</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Live working code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/relaxed-darwin-e6thp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)